# How to remove quote marks from variable in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have variable called `Query` in `Azure Data Factory`.

I expect value like: `Select CustomerName From Customer Where City = 'London'`

However I occasionally get value like: `'Select CustomerName From Customer Where City = 'London''`

I would like to remove single quote from beginning and end if value starts with `' Quote` should not be removed if value does not start with quote.

How to remove quote marks from variable?

Comment: This question looks similar to [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851936/how-to-pass-entire-sql-statement-to-lookup-activity-inside-foreach-of-azure-data) you previously asked. Would be great if you can check whether the answer there already solve your issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **`If()`** function in the expression to evaluate if the variable value starts with a **single quote (')**.

If the expression returns **true** then using substring **exclude** the first and last **single quotes** from the variable value. If **false** the value returns with **no change**.

**Example:**

Here, the variable (Query) value contains a single quote at the start and end of the value.

[image]

Using the `Set variable` activity, store the result in a variable (Final_query) after removing quotes if it contains at the start of the value.

```
@if(equals(substring(variables('Query'),0,1),''''),substring(variables('Query'),1,sub(length(variables('Query')),2)),variables('Query'))
```

[image]

**Output:**

Removed single quotes from start and end of the value.

[image]